# build.gradle file in android studio canary

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I use from Android Studio canary version. I want to use Firebase service. For that I should add this line to root build.gradle file.

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
```

But my build.gradle file is like this image:

[image]

How can I add Firebase in Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You can try to edit your `build.gradle` to look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
     maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Of course you can reomove lines that you think isn't useful. XD

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to add Firebase in project Android Studio is

Click tools > select Firebase
[image: Click tool > select Firebase]

After that side bar will display and u can select firebase service what you need
[image: After that side bar will display and u can select firebase service what you need]

Last, u will see step by step to using this firebase service easily
[image: Last, u will see step by step to using this firebase service easily]

I hope this will be help you
#CMIIW

Comment: Thanks but this way can't add classpath to build.gradle (in canary).